# get select box value Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I use laravel 5.4.

```
   <select name="type" id="type">
     <option value="0">title1</option>
     <option value="1" selected>title2</option>
     <option value="2">title3</option>
    </select>
```

I record the data to the database. But I can not get the value of the select box tag. I am using the following codes in Controller and as a result I get text.

```
$type = $request->get('type');
  or 
$type = Input::get('type');

print_r($type) ;
```

result: "title2"

I did not find any results in my research. Please help me.Is there a recommendation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the easiest way is `$request->type` to get value of select option in your controller ;)

Answer (score 2):

change `$request->get('type')` to `$request->input('type')`